# Streamline repetitive formula calculation in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Summary tab contains project name which is the name for remaining tab names in my google sheets as follows:

| TabName |
| --- |
| Project1 |
| Project2 |
| Project3 |

There may be up to 20 TabName defined but this is not necessary.  All project name tabs has the same format - 1 row contains the weekly start dates and column 1 has the resource names.  The following is what the project name tabs would look like -

**Project1 tab**

| Person | 1-Mar-2021 | 8-Mar-2021 | 15-Mar-2021 | 22-Mar-2021 | 29-Mar-2021 | 5-Apr-2021 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |  |  |  |
| Jane |  | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Abe |  |  | 5 |  | 5 |  |  |  |  |

Project2 begins at a different Start Week from Project1 and Project3.

**Project2 tab**

| Person | 4-Jan-2021 | 11-Jan-2021 | 18-Jan-2021 | 25-Jan-2021 | 1-Feb-2021 | 8-Feb-2021 | 15-Feb-2021 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |  |  |  |
| Mary |  | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Abe |  |  | 5 |  | 5 |  |  |  |  |

Project3 begins at a different Start Week from Project1 and Project2.

**Project3 tab**

| Person | 8-Feb-2021 | 15-Feb-2021 | 22-Feb-2021 | 1-Mar-2021 | 8-Mar-2021 | 15-Mar-2021 | 22-Mar-2021 | 29-Mar-2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |  |  |
| Mary |  | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| John |  |  | 5 |  | 5 |  |  |  |
| Marg |  |  |  |  |  | 3 | 3 | 3 |

Note, the start week in Row1Col2 may not be the same date for all projects.  For example, Project1 starts on Mar 1 while Project2 starts on Jan 4.  Also, not all resources are across all projects (e.g. Jane and Marg are only in one project).

In the summary tab, it should show the concatenation of all projects by resource and week as follows -

**Resource Weekly tab**

| Person | 4-Jan-2021 | 11-Jan-2021 | 18-Jan-2021 | 25-Jan-2021 | 1-Feb-2021 | 8-Feb-2021 | 15-Feb-2021 | 22-Feb-2021 | 1-Mar-2021 | 8-Mar-2021 | 15-Mar-2021 | 22-Mar-2021 | 29-Mar-2021 | 5-Apr-2021 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Project3 (5) | Project1 (2) | Project1 (2) Project3 (5) | Project1 (4) | Project1 (5) | Project1 (5) | Project1 (5) |  |  |  |
| Jane |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Project1 (1) |  | Project1 (1) | Project1 (1) |  |  |  |  |
| Joe | Project2 (2) | Project2 (2) | Project2 (4) | Project2 (5) | Project2 (5) | Project2 (5) Project3 (2) | Project3 (2) | Project3 (4) | Project3 (5) | Project3 (5) | Project3 (5) | Project3 (5) |  |  |  |  |  |
| Abe |  |  | Project2 (5) |  | Project2 (5) |  |  |  |  |  | Project1 (5) |  | Project1 (5) |  |  |  |  |
| Mary |  | Project2 (1) |  | Project2 (1) | Project2 (1) | Project2 (1) | Project3 (1) |  | Project3 (1) | Project3 (1) | Project3 (1) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Marg |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Project3 (3) | Project3 (3) | Project3 (3) |  |  |  |  |

Column 1, which contains the resource name and row 1 with the start dates are fixed (i.e. no calculation required).  Also, where a resource has more than one projects, the concatenated projects are separated by a line return.

I would also like that the concatenation calculation does not perform if the Start Week does not have a date OR if there is no resource name defined for that row.  The Summary tab will identify the number of project tabs that exists where the concatenation calculation needs to look for data.

I do have the Resource Weekly tab working using a very long SUMPRODUCT and INDIRECT.  However, the google sheet is now running much slower when I added this Resource Weekly sheet.

Is there a way to do this using app script?

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1giInVlEcmr1CeABqa1mM8HTrjtYy0LFPbvpHCNdus1w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. I could see your sample Spreadsheet. In order to confirm your goal, can you add the output situation you expect using your sample Spreadsheet? Because I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about the logic for achieving your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: The link is the file along with the SUMPRODUCT and INDIRECT formula contained in the Weekly tab.  This is a much shorter and simpler version of the actual formula.  For example, the project files would contain an additional column that denotes Y for remote work.  I would separate this as 2 separate lines with a notation at the beginning.  For example if Joe on Feb 8 working on Project2, if his 5 days on Project 2 was 3 days remote and 2 days onsite, the expected result would be Project2 (2) new line R Project2 (3) new line Project3 (2).

Comment: The expected results can be seen there with the formula calculation.  I would like to convert this repetitive formula to an app script so that my spreadsheet runs faster.  It is at least 20 times slower than it used to be ie. a sec and now 20 to 30 secs.

Comment: I have read that app script is the way to go.  Please note that there will only be one row for a resource and remote/onsite indicator.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and adding more information, I could confirm that the result situation you added is the same with the result of my sample script. So I proposed a sample script as an answer. If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the following situation using Google Apps Script. (The following result is from my sample script.)

  - From

    [image]
  - To

    [image]

In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve sheet names from "Summary" sheet.
2. Retrieve values from each project sheet and create an object for creating result values.
3. Create an result values for putting to "Weekly" sheet.
4. Put the result values to "Weekly" sheet.

When above flow is reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve sheet names from "Summary" sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const summarySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Summary");
  const sheetNames = summarySheet.getRange("A2:A" + summarySheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Retrieve values from each project sheet and create an object for creating result values.
  const obj = sheetNames.reduce((o, s) => {
    const [[, ...header], ...values] = ss.getSheetByName(s).getDataRange().getValues();
    header.forEach((h, i) => {
      const k = h.toISOString();
      if (o[k]) {
        values.forEach(v => {
          if (v[i + 1].toString() != "") o[k][v[0]] = (o[k][v[0]] ? `${o[k][v[0]]}\n` : "") + `${s} (${Number(v[i + 1])})`;
        });
      } else {
        o[k] = values.reduce((o2, v) => {
          if (v[i + 1].toString() != "") o2[v[0]] = `${s} (${Number(v[i + 1])})`;
          return o2;
        }, {});
      }
    });
    return o;
  }, {});

  // 3. Create an result values for putting to "Weekly" sheet.
  const weeklySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Weekly");
  const [[, ...header], ...values] = weeklySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const tempValues = header.reduce((ar, h) => {
    const k = h.toISOString();
    const temp = [];
    if (obj[k]) {
      values.forEach(([v]) => temp.push(obj[k][v] || ""));
      ar.push(temp);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const res = tempValues[0].map((_, j) => tempValues.map(row => row[j]));

  // 4. Put the result values to "Weekly" sheet.
  weeklySheet.getRange(2, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this sample script is used for your sample Spreadsheet, the result I showed in above images can be obtained.

#### Note:

- When I saw your updated sample Spreadsheet including the result sheet you expect, I noticed that the 1st row of "Weekly" sheet is empty. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet for the 1st time before you updated, the 1st row of "Weekly" sheet was the header row. So I'm confusing this. In this sample script, I prepared it as the situation that the 1st row of "Weekly" sheet is the header row. Please be careful this.
- **And also, this sample script is for your sample Spreadsheet. So, if the structure of each sheet of your actual situation is different from your sample Spreadsheet, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.**

  - So, please test the sample script using your sample Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

It seems that in your sample Spreadsheet, there are 2 kinds of Spreadsheets.

- One is that the 1st row of "Weekly" sheet is NOT empty.
- Another is that the 1st row of "Weekly" sheet is empty.

By this, I'm confusing about your situation. My above sample script is for the former situation. For example, when your current situation is changed to the latter situation, please modify above script as follows.

#### From:

```
  const [[, ...header], ...values] = weeklySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const tempValues = header.reduce((ar, h) => {
    const k = h.toISOString();
    const temp = [];
    if (obj[k]) {
      values.forEach(([v]) => temp.push(obj[k][v] || ""));
      ar.push(temp);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const res = tempValues[0].map((_, j) => tempValues.map(row => row[j]));

  // 4. Put the result values to "Weekly" sheet.
  weeklySheet.getRange(2, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
```

#### To:

```
  const [,[, ...header], ...values] = weeklySheet.getDataRange().getValues();  // Modified
  const tempValues = header.reduce((ar, h) => {
    const k = h.toISOString();
    const temp = [];
    if (obj[k]) {
      values.forEach(([v]) => temp.push(obj[k][v] || ""));
      ar.push(temp);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const res = tempValues[0].map((_, j) => tempValues.map(row => row[j]));

  // 4. Put the result values to "Weekly" sheet.
  weeklySheet.getRange(3, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);  // Modified
```

Comment: Thank you, Tanaika.  I received an error on line 29 and 30 saying "TypeError: h.toISOString is not a function" when I ran the script.

Comment: @Joyce Brown Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Now, I added one more script for the situation that the 1st row of "Weekly" sheet is empty. Could you please confirm it? If that is not the direct solution of your current issue, please provide your current Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating your issue. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Thank you so much.  I am able to execute the script and the results on the Weekly tab is what I expected.  I will take a look in detail of your code.  I will need to try to modify your script to take into account two columns - Remote which is the first column before the Resource name and Cost, which is the column after the resource name.  The Remote time would need to be separate out, which is denote by an R in front of the TabName.

Comment: Also, there are 3 additional tables which uses the same project tabs to obtain the information.  The second table is for all times, which is like the first but without the text in front of it.  The third table is for only times where the Remote column does not have a Y (i.e. blank/null).  The last table is for the cost for all projects except those that have the TabName ending in _FP or have a text of SaaS in the TabName.  The Cost is calculated for all non Remote time multiplied by the Cost.

Comment: My sample spreadsheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MzCm1yeqhU1I-cvlQoTBrfzybn5ktpvxeYhnud6eXms/edit#gid=1622332657.

Comment: @Joyce Brown Thank you for replying. From `Thank you so much. I am able to execute the script and the results on the Weekly tab is what I expected.`, I understood that my answer could resolve your question. I'm glad for it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike.  I have created another discussion post as you have suggested.  It is titled "Autocalculation of sheet using information from multiple sheets in same google sheets".  Thank you!

Comment: @Joyce Brown Thank you for your response. When I found it, I would like to check it.